# Is my app's displaying of email IDs illegal from a data privacy perspective?

Tags: data-protection, data-ownership, data-storage

I am building an app that will easily help connect Spotify playlist curators with artists who are trying to promote their music. As part of this, i would like my app to display names and business email/submission email of the curators so that they can independently be contacted by the artists to pitch their track. On my platform Payola (Taking money in return for playlist placements) is strictly prohibited and curators who request payment for playlist placements are not allowed on our platform.

Is displaying the curator email ID a violation of any law? In many cases, the email ID is already in the description of the Spotify playlist.

Do you see any other long term violation of any terms of conditions that my app is liable for?

Comment: How exactly are you "connecting Spotify playlist curators with artists"? By some automated means of retrieving user data from Spotify? Or from the individuals who sign up/use your App and share their data?

Comment: By automated means through Spotify's API. My app would display a list of available curators and display that playlist's metadata (Number of tracks, number of likes etc) along with the curators email ID. This will allow the artists pitching their track to email the curator directly via email.

Am I legally allowed to post these email IDs on a public website? Their email IDs are in most cases already available on their Spotify description. In other cases, i would get their email by checking their Instagram profile (Which usually has their email listed).

Comment: Are you adhering to Spotify's TOS for your use of their API? I.e., no automated scraping, user privacy, etc? https://www.spotify.com/us/legal/end-user-agreement/

Comment: Yes I am adhering to them. The data I am displaying is being sourced from other sources like Instagram. I was unable to find anything that mentions displaying the information available on Spotify, on my platform. Not sure if that violates user privacy

Comment: Would the email addresses be considered “business” info or personal?

Comment: How do you make sure that you do not harvest personal information, which is under protection by privacy laws? also, what incentive does your platform offer to playlist-makers if they can't get payment from musicians?

Comment: At this stage, I am not sure what constitutes "Personal Information". The information I will be posting is mostly email IDs that are already available either on the curators Instagram account (This is usually a business account) or listed in Spotify's playlist description itself. Does that make it a business email?

@Trish - I currently do not offer any incentives to playlist-makers to ensure they don't get paid for placements. I would have a disclaimer at the time of sign up and also mention in my terms and conditions, that this is against terms of use.

Comment: Private emails are Personal Information under GDPR. And if the playlist maker has nothing from your platform: **why** should they want to use it? You disincentive them from your platform

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, playlist makers will not use this platform primarily. It will be used by artists who are looking to pitch to playlist makers. 
I am sourcing a large collection of playlists and including the playlist makes email ID in my app. In a lot of cases, the playlist maker does not even know that I have done this. i will do my best to notify them that their information is live on my platform and if any objection to this, I will instantly take it down. But there is no guarantee that I get written consent from all the sourced playlist makers.